# Changing widget in QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 custom widgets in my stacked widget and I want to be able to change from one to the other I press a button, however when I currently click it the program just terminates.

Here is the first custom widget .cpp:

```
 #include "loginpage.h"
 #include "ui_loginpage.h"

 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "mainpage.h"

 #include "QtGui"


 LoginPage::LoginPage(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::LoginPage)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);


     connect(ui->loginPushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(doLogin()));
 }

 LoginPage::~LoginPage()
 {
     delete ui;
 }

 QString LoginPage::getUsername()
 {
     QString userName = ui->usernameLineEdit->text();
     return userName;
 }

 QString LoginPage::getPassword()
 {
     QString passWord = ui->passwordLineEdit->text();
     return passWord;
 }

 void LoginPage::doLogin()
 {
     QString username = getUsername();
     QString password = getPassword();
     bool check = checkCredentials(password, username);

     if(check == true)
     {
         MainWindow *main;
         main = new MainWindow;
         main->test();

     }else
     {
         QMessageBox::information(this, tr("incorrect"), tr("incorrect"));
     }


 }

...
```

Here is the main window .cpp:

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
 #include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 #include "loginpage.h"
 #include "ui_loginpage.h"

 #include "mainpage.h"

 #include <QtGui>

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {

     ui->setupUi(this);

 }

 MainWindow::~MainWindow()
 {
     delete ui;
 }

 void MainWindow::test()
 {
     ui->stackedWidget->setCurrentIndex(1);

 }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: where do you `show()` your `MainWindow` ? And please, fix that  call on the uninitialized pointer that is mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean it crashes instead of terminates. In your `doLogin()` you write

```
MainWindow *main;
main->test();
```

But at that point `main` is still a null pointer. So calling `test()` makes no sense. As a result, your program is likely to crash.

Comment: Thankyou, I changed it to this:   MainWindow *main;
     main = new MainWindow;
     main->test(); however the stackedwidget still doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

Well first `qDebug()` is a Qt programmers friend, you can put `qDebug() << "In x function"` and see where the code is bailing. Without being able to see your UI file or when the error occurs I'd guess you're setting currentIndex of the QStackedWidget to 1 when it only has one widget associated. Double check that the UI is setup correctly, and check your debug traces to see where it's crashing.